# When setting default arguments to a function in Python using None, why I am getting 'UnboundLocalError'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

In the following function ,clc, whenever I fail to pass the third argument 'z', I want the fuction to automatically perform addition. (i.e) If I pass only two 
 arguments (150,200), I want to get the same result as I do when I pass (150,200,'a'). Unfortunately I am getting a traceback that 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment'. Can anyone please explain why I get this error? Thanks.

```
def clc(x,y,z=None):
    if (z=='a') or (z is None):
        r=x+y
    elif z=='s':
        r=x-y
    elif z=='m':
        r=x*y
    elif z=='d':
        r=x/y
    elif z=='mod':
        r=x%y
    elif z=='ex':
        r=x**y
    return r
while True:
    a=int(input('Enter a number:\t '))
    b=int(input('Enter a number:\t '))
    op=input('enter the operation:\t')
    answer=clc(a,b,op)
    print('the answer is',answer)
    query=input('If you want to continue, please press Enter\t')
    if len(query)>0:
        break
```

Edit: Thanks to PM2Ring for his explanation which cleared my error! This is his reply : 'If you just hit Enter at the 'enter the operation' prompt then op gets assigned the empty string '', it's not None. And then when you call clc(a,b,op) none of your if tests are True, and so r never gets assigned a value. The if statement I posted earlier handles that empty string case.'

Comment: Something never meets the criteria of `if` or the `elif`s so `r` never gets set... so depending what you're trying to do - you either want a default value set to start with or you want an `else` to handle it. This isn't to do with your default argument

Comment: I don't see anywhere in that code where you call `clc` without passing a third arg.

Comment: Perhaps you want `if z == 'a' or z == '' or z is None:`

Comment: @ PM 2Ring  'None' not the way to pass default/optional argument?  Atleast that's what I assumed? Can you please explain?

Comment: Yes, `None` is a perfectly good default argument. But it never gets used in your code because you _always_ call `clc` with three arguments: `a`, `b` and `op`.

Comment: @PM2Ring  Wouldn't this expression if (z=='a') or (z is None)  returns a binary value , if I not pass the argument for z?  Can you please explain how to pass an optional argument using None then?

Comment: Just like you've done it there: `def clc(x,y,z=None):`. And then you could call it like `result = clc(a, b)`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh, I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: If you just hit `Enter` at the 'enter the operation' prompt then `op` gets assigned the empty string `''`, it's not `None`. And then when you call `clc(a,b,op)` none of your `if` tests are True, and so `r` never gets assigned a value. The `if` statement I posted earlier handles that empty string case.

Answer (score 0):

Something tells me your input to `op` does not fit the bill for any of those `if` statements to get triggered, resulting in `r` never being defined or returned. One option would be to declare `r = None` outside the conditional block, so you get rid of that error.

However, if you're working with simple arithmetic operations (involving two operands only), I'd recommend keeping a dictionary of operations, and then invoking the correct one as needed.

```
import operator

_f = {'a' : operator.add, 's' : operator.sub, 'm' : operator.mul, 'd' : operator.div} 
def clc(x, y, op=None):
    return _f.get(op, operator.add)(x, y)
```

As an aside, as [PM 2Ring remarked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863394/when-setting-default-arguments-to-a-function-in-python-using-none-why-i-am-gett/46863436#comment80674286_46863394), if you want the default argument to come into play, don't pass anything to `op`.

---

Unfortunately, if you're looking to penalising invalid inputs, the function above needs modification, because it is highly tolerant to all invalid/missing inputs, defaulting to addition in each case. You can make a small change to get this to work, however, using the *EAFP* approach with exception handling.

```
_f.update({None : operator.add})
def clc(x, y, op=None):
    try:
       return _f[op](x, y)
    except KeyError:
        return "Invalid Operation"
```

Comment: Your `.get` here will perform addition for invalid operations not just where it isn't supplied...

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the line `op=input('enter the operation:\t')`. If you enter nothing, it still returns `''`, an empty string, so for the `z` argument, you pass in `''`. The interpreter runs through all of your `if` and `elif` statements, and none of them are satisfied, so it just returns `r`. However, `r` has not been assigned any value, so an exception is raised.

Instead, you should write something like this

```
def clc(x,y,z):
    if z=='a' or z=='':
        r=x+y
    elif z=='s':
        r=x-y
    elif z=='m':
        r=x*y
    elif z=='d':
        r=x/y
    elif z=='mod':
        r=x%y
    elif z=='ex':
        r=x**y
    else:
        return 'N/A'
    return r
while True:
    a=int(input('Enter a number:\t '))
    b=int(input('Enter a number:\t '))
    op=input('enter the operation:\t')
    answer=clc(a,b,op)
    print('the answer is',answer)
    query=input('If you want to continue, please press Enter\t')
    if len(query)>0:
        break
```

Comment: That's still not correct.  Better would be `if z == 'a' or z is None` and make sure to have a case that returns a default value for `r`.  Otherwise if `z` matches none of the cases in the `if` statement you will get an `UnboundLocalError`.  Never use a variable if there are cases where it can be not assigned.

Comment: `z` can't equal `'a'` and `None` at the same time. Also, `r` shouldn't need to have a default value. It should always be assigned to something through some operation.

Comment: That should be `or` obviously.  My point is that your "solution" doesn't work  because it still allows `r` to be unassigned.

Comment: How about after the last `elif` statement, it should say: `else: return 'N/A'`